# how to know AID on a chip card using PCSC card reader?

Tags: smartcard

I have a PCSC card reader with it's drivers installed on Windows system. I'm trying to read a chip card. I don't have the AID of the application on the chip. The card provider gave me a tool to read the card but didn't provide the AID. I'm not able to read it as the tool keeps looking for the AID on the card, which I don't have, and returns with false. Is there a way( tool) to retrieve the AID from the card chip itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibility one: The card has an EF.DIR (typical file ID in MF: 0x2F00), which contains all AIDs of applications present on the card.

Possibility two: The card supports selection via partial AID, so you just need to supply the first byte of it and can evaluate the full response to find out the complete AID.

Unfortunately neither is granted to be supported.